# g++ compiler ignoring const return type

Tags: c++, g++, constants, return-type

I'm one of these types of people who thinks "if it shouldn't be able to change, then it should be `const`". Perhaps I take `const` to the extreme by doing this, but, since my function return types generally should not be able to change, I declare all my functions to return `const`. (Unless they return `void` of course - does it even make sense to return by `const void`?)

You probably think either I'm kind of nutty, and I'm wearing out my keyboard typing stuff I don't need to, or that returning const makes sense because you already use it yourself. Or maybe you're thinking neither of those things in which case I guessed incorrectly.

I've compiled my program using g++4.8, and enabled the compiler switch `-Wextra`. When doing so, g++ warns me that it ignores *every single one* of my return statements. None of them are returning by `const`. This makes no difference after compiling obviously, but I wanted to know is there a way of forcing g++ to compile and pay some attention to my `const` return types.

More importantly, why does g++ ignore the `const` -- or is it simply because I'm nutty and g++ thinks returning `const` is unnecessary?

As requested: Example...

`inline const bool collisionTest(...) { ... }`

`warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type`

Comment: Can you add a simple example code to your question? And the text of the warning?

Comment: In my experience, const is useful in the following cases: const pointers or references, const member functions, compile-time constants (const int size = 10 for example) and const global variables (static const std::string name = "harry"). Everything else doesn't really matter.

Comment: @NeilKirk The same can be said for function parameters... If you pass `double _time` as an argument, then you are allowed to mod it... It's not a reference so nothing will change except in the scope of the function... but if I don't specifically want my function to use that variable (exception would be in a loop for example) then I would pass in a `const double _time` .

Comment: @EdwardBird True it can be helpful to const the parameters to prevent accidental change.

Comment: @NeilKirk Especially if you're modifying some code at a later date

Comment: "@gx_ Okay, but why?" Because it makes sense to provide all useful information when you ask a question. For example, we can now see that the warning does _not_ actually say that g++ ignores your return statements, but that it ignores _types qualifiers_ on the return types. We can also see that it warns for `const bool` but I verified that it doesn't for `const Foo` (where `Foo` is a class), so the fact that all your functions return _"built-in" types_ (as opposed to _user-defined_) is another _relevant_ and _useful_ information that you didn't mention.

Comment: @gx_ If you want to cause problems rather than being helpful I would rather you just didn't bother commenting to be honest.

Comment: Sorry if I gave this wrong impression. I was just trying to point out this simple thing: the more information you provide about your problem, the more you _help your readers_ help _you_ (and the more likely you are to get actually useful answers). Among the obvious to me, when I get a compiler error/warning I just feel "natural" to copy-paste it in the question. Also I usually try to post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) (or at least some code example) so that the readers can experiment on their different platforms and compare the results with mine (also, code is more precise than English text).

Answer (score 10):

It doesn't ignore it, it's just useless if you return primitive types by value.

Returning by value means you can't modify whatever it is you returned anyways, because it's an r-value. The const would be redundant.

See:

```
int foo();
```

How would you modify the return?

```
foo() = 4;
```

would yield a compiler error.

If you return a reference though, the const does matter:

```
int& foo();
const int& goo();

foo() = 42;  //okay 
goo() = 42;  //error
```

Comment: In c++11 you can, though I guess a const r value reference is pointless

Comment: Ah thanks, I didn't realize that would give a compiler error!

Comment: "Returning by value means you can't modify whatever it is you returned anyways" Hop hop hop, did you forget user-defined types? `std::string foo() { return "bar"; }` then `std::string s = "hello"; foo().swap(s);` (`std::string::swap` is a _non_-const member function). http://ideone.com/KK1qiW

Comment: It is only for primitive types!

Comment: @gx_ I'd argue the return string isn't modified.

Comment: But, what in case of returning user defined types by value? like an object of a class.

Comment: @UchiaItachi the const does make a difference then.

Comment: @EdwardBird rvalue references, arguably the most important new feature of c++11, [read up](http://thbecker.net/articles/rvalue_references/section_01.html)

Comment: @gx_ (sorry that was an attempt at trolling) :)

Comment: @LuchianGrigore (ok :) ) You could add to your answer that return by _const value_ is considered bad practice now (in C++11), because: for _primitive types_ it's _redundant_ (and ignored, as per gcc's warning) and, most important, for _user-defined types_ it will _prevent move semantics_ (and the useful optimization).